# Media query not detecting the given range according to the screen size

Tags: css, media-queries

I am working on a media query for a website. I have done almost 95% of it without any issue.

Currently, I am not being able to fix one issue which is, I wrote CSS for the `378px` sized screen but when I check the responsiveness it is detecting from the range of `991px`. 
I am attaching it.
[image: Code inspection]

And when I am in the 378px screen,

[image: 378px screen]

Can you guys help me with what's going wrong?

Comment: pls add the code instead picture

Comment: <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
   <img class="lazyload footer-apple" style="width: 85%;float: right;"
                                 src="images/appstore.png"
                                 alt="Apple-store"/>
                        </a>

Comment: Did you add this code on header?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: yes I did add it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media queries below code:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .example {background: blue;}
}

@media (min-width: 378px)  and (max-width: 479px) {
    .example {background: orange;}
}

@media (max-width: 378px) {
    .example {background: red;}
}
```

Comment: But I wanted to target screens under 378px but it's not detecting that, instead it is detecting the 991px.

Comment: do you test max-width:378px

Comment: please share your code on jsfiddle or codepen Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your media query working fine but you not getting output due to line number position.

I can see:

```
@media (max-width: 378px) // Line number showing mg.css:13
```

And

```
@media (max-width: 991px) // Line number showing mg.css:925
```

So when selector priority is same then it work only last lines because CSS control read top to bottom and both media query is active.

**Solution:**

You can overcome this situation two way:

**a.** By adding `378px` code after `991px` code.

**b.** By adding CSS priority selector like following:

```
@media (max-width: 378px) {
    .anothers-selector .example {background: red;}
}
```

Comment: Ok let me check this and get back to you soon!